# Boot VMWare from USB image with data persistence

Tags: boot, usb, vmware, persistence

I have a Linux  live USB with persistence. USB boots and works fine in VMWare when added as Generic SCSI drive.

I made an image of it on my local machine. I have booted from this image as CD/DVD drive image and it boots fine. However the persistence is lost, which kind of makes sense since a CD/DVD drive is supposed to be read-only.

Is there any way to boot this image directly in VMWare without losing the persistence?

Host operating system is Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the USB image to VHD format.
2. Go to Windows disk management and attach the VHD image (Action -> Attach VHD).
3. Windows should have created a new disk with your mounted VHD. Note the disk number.
4. Go to the settings of your VMWare machine (I suggest you restart VMWare if it was already open).
5. Add a new hard disk and select "Use a Physical Disk".
6. Select the physical disk with the number of the mounted VHD from the drop-down of available disks. If the disk does not appear, restart VMWare.
7. Profit.